# Spring webapp shutdown and terminating threads

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

Class A

```
public Data getData(final String id){

   if(notAvailable(id)){

      classB.doSomethingAsync();
      throw new NotAvailableException();

   }
   else {
       return getData(id);
   }
}
```

Class B

```
@Async
public void doSomethingAsync()
{
   int count = 100;
   while (count > 0)
   {
      count--;
      System.out.println(times);
      try
      {
         Thread.sleep(5000); 
      }
      catch (final InterruptedException e)
      {
         System.out.println("Sleep interrupted. Exiting");
         return;
      }
   }
}
```

Say all this is running in a web-app. A request is made and ClassA.getData() method is called. The code path follows the case when notAvailable() return true, and we call ClassB.doSomethingAsync() and throw the exception to the client from ClassA.

My question is, when the web-app is shutdown, does the while loop in Class B exit prematurely without waiting for the count to reach zero?

I have been seeing mixed results during testing and I'd like someone to give a definite answer as to what happens.The application is running under Jetty.

Comment: What are some of the mixed results you've seen?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have seen times when the application shuts down as if the thread was interrupted and at times the loop continues to execute until the count reaches zero. I am thinking that those times when then interrupt happened, the shutdown arrived at the point in time when the loop is in the 5 second sleep (Thread.sleep).    I am wondering if Class B should have a hook into the shutdown of the application via @PreDestroy where a field (i.e., isShuttingDown) can be set to true, and the loop can check this field on each iteration.